# Why does this produce only one button on the grid?

Tags: java, javafx

When I run this, it creates only one button. I'm trying to create a gridPane of buttons, 10x10 and when a button is clicked it would send the row column(x,y) coordinates to another class which would handle its purpose (a battleship game)

```
    Button button[][] = new Button[10][10];
    public static int rows, columns, gridSize;

    for (rows = 0; rows < 10; rows++) {
        for (columns = 0; columns < 10; columns++) {
            button[rows][columns] = new Button();
            button[rows][columns].setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
            button[rows][columns].setPrefSize(50, 50);

            button[rows][columns].setOnMouseClicked(new clickEvents(rows, columns));
            //no setters, directly passed rows and cols to clickEvents Class

            tileGrid.getChildren().add(button[rows][columns]); //adds buttons to the tile grid
        }
    }

    container.getChildren().addAll(tileGrid);

    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(container);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane));
    primaryStage.show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is the one giving you issues

```
tileGrid.getChildren().add(button[rows][columns]);
```

This is due to the fact that you are incorrectly adding your buttons. If you try something like

```
tileGrid.add(
        button[rows][columns],    // Specific node in the array
        columns,                  // Set the specific column
        rows                      // Set the specific row
); //adds buttons to the tile grid
```

it should work here is the full example code

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button[][] = new Button[10][10];
        int rows, columns, gridSize;

        GridPane tileGrid = new GridPane();

        for (rows = 0; rows < 10; rows++) {
            for (columns = 0; columns < 10; columns++) {
                button[rows][columns] = new Button();
                button[rows][columns].setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
                button[rows][columns].setPrefSize(50, 50);

                //button[rows][columns].setOnMouseClicked(new clickEvents(rows, columns));
                //no setters, directly passed rows and cols to clickEvents Class

                tileGrid.add(
                        button[rows][columns],   // Specific node in the array
                        columns,                 // Set the specific column
                        rows                     // Set the specific row
                ); //adds buttons to the tile grid
            }
        }

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(new VBox(tileGrid));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

EDIT: 2 Min too slow but I'm going to leave it here so he can see the example if he needs it

Comment: so basically i was just adding the node to the gridpane without specifying the children of the node?

Comment: No, a node which you add to the GridPane doesn't need to have any children.  You were adding the node to the GridPane but not setting constraints on the node as to which grid location within the pane to place the node.  So the nodes were all just being added to the GridPane at the default 0,0 location (all stacked on top of each other).

Answer (score 5):

You aren't telling the system where to put the button in the GridPane.

Use [`gridPane.add(child, colIndex, rowIndex)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#add(javafx.scene.Node,int,int)):

```
tileGrid.add(button[row][column], column, row);
```

I fixed spelling and removed plurality (trailing 's') from the row, column variables.

Alternately, you could [set constraints](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setConstraints(javafx.scene.Node,int,int)) on the node in the GridPane:

```
tileGrid.getChildren().add(button[row][column]);
GridPane.setConstraints(button[row][column], column, row);
```

But it is a less verbose to use the add method which specifies the constraints in initial add parameters (as in the prior example).

Without any constraints on the nodes added as children to the grid, all the children will be located at the default 0,0 grid location (all stacked on top of each other).